# Autocomplete on multiple languages combined in a single file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, autocomplete, notepad++

Notepad has some nice autocomplete features. It adds close tags to HTML and XML and code completion for different languages. I am looking for a way to combine languages since with web design you use a lot of different ones in a single file (css, xml, html, php, js, jquery, etc). Despite what I have read (js should already be integrated into HTML) I cannot get this to work.

When I select HTML I only get HTML autocomplete and when I select PHP I only get PHP autocomplete. I love the lightweight notepad environment but this could speed up workflow a lot. There is a option to add a user defined language but I have no clue how to combine these languages.

So is there a way I can combine multiple languages for autocomplete in notepad++?

Below is a screenshot where we can see autocomplete working on multiple languages:
[image]

Comment: You really _shouldn't_ be using multiple languages bundled into one file unless you're shoehorning something together; generally, good practice is to completely separate them where possible. Hodgepodge files like this should be a deterrent for creating more. Of course, sometimes, just _sometimes_, we can't avoid it - making it easier to manage likely just makes it easier to become complacent.

Comment: Possible duplicate question on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/251749/how-can-i-add-autocomplete-in-notepad-for-javascript-in-an-html-file and related question on SE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012569/how-can-i-add-autocomplete-in-notepad-for-javascript-in-an-html-file

Comment: @GrantThomas So i should separate every JS and PHP script from HTML? I think every tutorial on the web needs to be rewritten if this is the case. What if i want to feed some PHP generated HTML to a page? Or have many small JQuery scripts on the page. What if i have a simple page that needs php sessions? Could you point me to a source where this is clearly explained and practiced?

Comment: @DavidVogel Slightly related but i need multiple languages, they are also quite old. The thought of putting a bounty on one of those crossed my mind but i figured i would not get the answer i want.

Answer (score 0):

In **SynWrite** editor it's OK to call JS autocomplete inside JS part (it's marked with `<script>` e.g.) and PHP autocomplete in PHP part (marked with `<?php ?>`) and etc. PHP lexer has inline HTML support, HTML has inline JS support etc.